# Trying to crunch ruby code to minimum lines

Tags: ruby

Okay, so I'm trying to crunch this system as much as possible this is as far as I got it crunched down to

```
def process(data)
    data = data.split("\r\n\x00").map{|x| x.split(":")}
    data.each do |a|
        event,data = a[0],a[1..-1]
        print event
    end

end
```

What it does it when you put a byte in(In my case from a socket) it would search for something like, "event:eventdata\r\n\x00" only more then one of these then it would separate and get rid of the "terminator"("\r\n\x00") and leave the event and the list of data

Is it possible to crunch it down even more? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're afraid to run out of LOCs, then have this one-liner.

```
def process(data)
  data.split("\r\n\x00").map{|x| x.split(":")}.each {|a| event,data = a[0],a[1..-1]; print event}
end
```

Hopefully, you'll see that the most terse code is not always the best one.

I see no practical point in "crunching down" piece of code. For entertainment only, maybe. Production code should be readable, that's most important.

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for. I just didn't know how to crunch it up to that point, and I see what your saying.

Comment: Chuck's answer suggests an actual improvement to the code. But mine contains a piece of advice :)

Answer (score 2):

You never do anything with `data` after `data.each do |a|`, so the assignment in the loop is extraneous. You can simply do:

```
 data.split("\r\n\x00").map {|x| x.split(':')[0]}.each {|x| print x}
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Indeed it is. Sorry, I was just looking at a similar piece of code and it leaked into my brain.

Answer (score 2):

```
def process(data)
  data.split("\r\n\x00").each{|x| print x[/[^:]*/]}
end
```

or with `split`

```
def process(data)
  data.split("\r\n\x00").map{|x| x.split(":", 2)}.each{|event, _| print event}
end
```

Comment: `split` looks more readable, don't you think? But this is a possibility to shorten the code, yes.

Comment: With `split`, I will go differently.